# Multiple Query to Single Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working with SQL Server 2008.

I created a stored procedure like this:

```
SELECT  SUM(m.BookingAmt) + SUM(m.FormFee) AS 'SIP'
FROM    dbo.Member AS m
    INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster AS pm ON m.PlanId = pm.PlanId
    INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster AS ptm ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
WHERE   ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'true'
    AND m.CompanyId = @CompanyId
    AND m.CscId = @CscId
    AND m.CommencementDate = @Date

SELECT  SUM(i.PaymentAmt) + SUM(m.FormFee) AS 'Fresh'
FROM    dbo.Installment AS i
    INNER JOIN dbo.Member AS m ON i.MemberId = m.MemberId
    INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster AS pm ON i.PlanId = pm.PlanId
    INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster AS ptm ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
WHERE   i.InstallmentNo = 1
    AND m.CompanyId = @CompanyId
    AND m.CscId = @CscId
    AND i.PaymentDate = @Date
    AND ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'false'

SELECT  SUM(i.PaymentAmt) AS '1stYear'
FROM    dbo.Installment AS i
    INNER JOIN dbo.Member AS m ON i.MemberId = m.MemberId
WHERE   i.InstallmentNo > 1
    AND i.InstallmentNo < 13
    AND m.CompanyId = @CompanyId
    AND m.CscId = @CscId
    AND i.PaymentDate = @Date


SELECT  SUM(i.PaymentAmt) AS '2ndYear'
FROM    dbo.Installment AS i
    INNER JOIN dbo.Member AS m ON i.MemberId = m.MemberId
WHERE   i.InstallmentNo > 12
    AND i.InstallmentNo < 25
    AND m.CompanyId = @CompanyId
    AND m.CscId = @CscId
    AND i.PaymentDate = @Date

SELECT  SUM(i.PaymentAmt) AS '3rdYear'
FROM    dbo.Installment AS i
    INNER JOIN dbo.Member AS m ON i.MemberId = m.MemberId
WHERE   i.InstallmentNo > 24
    AND i.InstallmentNo < 37
    AND m.CompanyId = @CompanyId
    AND m.CscId = @CscId
    AND i.PaymentDate = @Date

SELECT  SUM(i.PaymentAmt) AS '4thYear'
FROM    dbo.Installment AS i
    INNER JOIN dbo.Member AS m ON i.MemberId = m.MemberId
WHERE   i.InstallmentNo > 36
    AND m.CompanyId = @CompanyId
    AND m.CscId = @CscId
    AND i.PaymentDate = @Date
```

but I want to get result like this...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  Date       | SIP  |  Fresh  | 1stYear | 2ndYear | 3rdYear | 4thYear |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  01/02/2013 | 2000 |  2500   |  5000   |  3500   |  4500   |  6500   |
 ------------------------------------------------------- --------------
  02/02/2013 | 6500 |  5000   |  1500   |  4500   |   3520  |  1852   |
  --------------------------------------------------------------------
  03/02/2013 | 2560 |  2500   |  3500   |  4500   |  2000   |   2000  |
```

How can I get above result using one query? Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consolidate the queries that generate the `1stYear`, `2ndYear`, etc by using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to create columns instead of rows.

Then you can create subqueries for the other two, finally joining them all together on the date. So your final query could be:

```
SELECT coalesce(q1.CommencementDate, q2.PaymentDate, q3.PaymentDate) date,
  q1.SIP,
  q2.Fresh,
  q3.[1stYear],
  q3.[2ndYear],
  q3.[3rdYear],
  q3.[4thYear]
FROM
(
  SELECT m.CommencementDate,
    SUM(m.BookingAmt) + SUM(m.FormFee) AS 'SIP'
  FROM dbo.Member AS m
  INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster AS pm 
    ON m.PlanId = pm.PlanId
  INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster AS ptm 
    ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
  WHERE ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'true'
    AND m.CompanyId = @CompanyId
    AND m.CscId = @CscId
    AND m.CommencementDate = @Date
) q1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT i.PaymentDate,
    SUM(i.PaymentAmt) + SUM(m.FormFee) AS 'Fresh'
  FROM dbo.Installment AS i
  INNER JOIN dbo.Member AS m 
    ON i.MemberId = m.MemberId
  INNER JOIN dbo.PlanMaster AS pm 
    ON i.PlanId = pm.PlanId
  INNER JOIN dbo.PlanTypeMaster AS ptm 
    ON pm.PlanTypeId = ptm.PlanTypeId
  WHERE i.InstallmentNo = 1
    AND m.CompanyId = @CompanyId
    AND m.CscId = @CscId
    AND i.PaymentDate = @Date
    AND ptm.IsSingleInstallment = 'false'
) q2
  ON q1.CommencementDate = q2.PaymentDate
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT i.PaymentDate,
    sum(case 
          when i.InstallmentNo > 1 AND i.InstallmentNo < 13
          then i.PaymentAmt else 0 end) AS [1stYear],
    sum(case 
          when i.InstallmentNo > 12 AND i.InstallmentNo < 25
          then i.PaymentAmt else 0 end) AS [2ndYear],
    sum(case 
          when i.InstallmentNo > 24 AND i.InstallmentNo < 37
          then i.PaymentAmt else 0 end) AS [3rdYear],
    sum(case 
          when i.InstallmentNo > 36
          then i.PaymentAmt else 0 end) AS [4thYear]
  SUM(i.PaymentAmt) AS '1stYear'
  FROM dbo.Installment AS i
  INNER JOIN dbo.Member AS m 
    ON i.MemberId = m.MemberId
  WHERE m.CompanyId = @CompanyId
    AND m.CscId = @CscId
    AND i.PaymentDate = @Date
  GROUP BY i.PaymentDate
) q3
  ON q1.CommencementDate = q3.PaymentDate;
```